# Virtually duplicate page with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

For a project, I need to duplicate some pages. My pages have URLs like :

```
http://www.domain.com/my-page1/
http://www.domain.com/my-page2/
http://www.domain.com/my-page3/
```

I need to have (both with /virtual/ and without have to exist, so I don't need a redirection) :

```
http://www.domain.com/virtual/my-page1/
http://www.domain.com/virtual/my-page2/
http://www.domain.com/virtual/my-page3/
```

I want to know if is it possible to achieve this with htaccess ?
Moreover, I have to manage some exceptions because this page exists...

```
http://www.domain.com/virtual/
```

...and I dont want to duplicate it.

Comment: What do you mean by _duplicate a page_? Do you want one page to be accessible on multiple URLs? If so, can you describe the patterns?

Comment: Dude we need to see your current code in order to help you.

Comment: @PanamaJack : I dont have current code, my htaccess is empty.

Comment: @Halcyon : Right, I need all my pages be accessible on the root folder and on a virtual folder, I need to make "duplicate content"

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^virtual/(.+)$ /$1
</IfModule>
```

(Place it into the root directory.)

Comment: Just replaced `(.*)` with `(.+)` since you do not seem to rewrite the URL for the `/virtual/` base directory.

Comment: Does your web server allow the usage of `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to mention that I was using Wordpress and it already has some rewrite rules

Comment: You need to place the rules in front of Wordpress' rules. Did you do that?